# Transformer tutorial with tensorflow: GradientTape outside the with statment but still working

Tags: python, tensorflow, with-statement, transformer-model, gradienttape

Applying the tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer#training_and_checkpointing) on how to implement a transformer model I had some doubts on the training process.

The train_step function is implemented as:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=train_step_signature)
def train_step(inp, tar):
  tar_inp = tar[:, :-1]
  tar_real = tar[:, 1:]

  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions, _ = transformer([inp, tar_inp],
                                 training = True)
    loss = loss_function(tar_real, predictions)

  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, transformer.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, transformer.trainable_variables))

  train_loss(loss)
  train_accuracy(accuracy_function(tar_real, predictions))
```

We can see that `tf.GradientTape()` is defined as tape in a with statment. That works, but I don't understand how tape can be called outside the statement with:

```
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, transformer.trainable_variables)
```

Shouldn't tape be closed at the end of the with statement?

I implemented the code from the tutorial and it works as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most context managers used in `with` statements such as `with <ContextManager> as <Var>` are written to delete `<Var>` at the end of the block, but this is not actually a requirement.

The original proposal for adding the `with` statement in python 2.5 shows that at the end of the block, the `__exit__` method is called from the context manager, which in this case is `tf.GradientTape().__exit__`. If this method does not explicitly delete `<Var>`, then it will persist.

In tensorflow, it appears the developers made the decision to not delete this variable so that users can take advantage of the `with` keyword and also use the resulting `tape` object later on.

Additional information:
[PEP 343 – The “with” Statement](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/#:%7E:text=The%20translation%20of%20the%20above%20statement%20is%3A)